# Using var socket = chrome.sockets.tcpServer; in a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I was trying to open a tct server in a chrome extension browser action.

When I try to do it, an exception is shown in this line:

```
var socket = chrome.sockets.tcpServer;
```

The error is:

[image]

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: No, extensions [don't have `sockets` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index).

Comment: So, is it possible to launch an external application from a Chrome Extension?

Comment: See [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).